# resize several sheets and save as PDF

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I need do resize several sheets in order to get them always on the same size...and then save all of them as a PDF file. I do not know VBA so I'm doing a "frankestein code" getting pieces here and there.

What I get is the following code, that works for T1 sheet, but not for the other T2 and T3 sheets.How can I include them??

```
Sub Imprimir_PDF()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("T1")

'find the last row with formatting, to be included in print range
lastRow = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ws.Range("A2:CK" & lastRow).Address

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("T1", "T2", "T3")).Select

Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="C:\PaintChecker\Camadas\temp.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This takes your code, and substitutes the part where you get the last Row with a short loop and set all three sheets print area in the loop.

Then prints all three out into the same PDF as is indicated by your select statement of the array.

untested:

```
Sub Imprimir_PDF()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim count As Long
Dim sheet As String

'find the last row with formatting, to be included in print range
For count = 1 To 3
    sheet = "T" & count
    lastRow = Sheets(sheet).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row
    Sheets(sheet).PageSetup.PrintArea = Sheets(sheet).Range("A2:CK" & lastRow).Address
Next count

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("T1", "T2", "T3")).Select

Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    fileName:="C:\PaintChecker\Camadas\temp.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this:

```
Sub MakePDFs()

    Dim sheetsToTouch As Variant
    sheetsToTouch = Array("T1", "T2", "T3")
    Dim sheetName As Variant

    For Each sheetName In sheetsToTouch
        Sheets(sheetName).Activate
        ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:CK" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).Address
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:="C:\PaintChecker\Camadas\" & sheetName & ".pdf", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I think the problem here is that the OP was trying to print them all in ONE pdf.  I could be mistaken.  Otherwise, nice use of the array.